# Java statement with less than equal to on the right side

Tags: java, syntax

Here's a line from a large Java program which compiles without errors. I'm unable to understand how the <= operator is being used on the right side of assignment statement:

```
converged = measure.distance(centroid.getLengthSquared(), centroid, getCenter()) <= convergenceDelta;
```

Is this some obscure Java feature?

Comment: The question has been answered, however since you asked, convergence is a boolean, measure.distance returns float and convergenceDelta is of type float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not.

As you will see `converged` will be of `boolean` type.

It will be exactly the same as saying

```
boolean foo = 2 <= 3;
```

So, probably in your code `measure.distance(centroid.getLengthSquared(), centroid, getCenter())` returns a number which is then compared using the relational `<=` operator 
with `convergenceDelta;`. The result will be `true` or `false`, a boolean value which will
be saved at `converged`.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. `<=` and the other relational operators return boolean values. If `converged` is a boolean variable, you can assign that value to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is setting converged to the truth statement of the distance being less than or equal to the value on the variable convergenceDelta.

Answer (score 0):

<= is a binary operator like any other. The value of it is true if LHS <= RHS, and false if not.

So in this case, if the distance is less than the convergence delta it's considered to have converged.